# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity: possible to map SQL JSON column properties to individual columns in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a copy activity to read data from an Azure SQL DB source and write it into a Kusto sink.

In my source, the column named `RawJson` contains JSON stored as an `nvarchar(max)`.

The structure of the JSON is something like this:

```json
{
  "id" : 1,
  "text" : "Some text",
  "foo" : "bar"
}
```

My Kusto table has dedicated columns for all properties found in the JSON: `Id`, `Text`, `Foo`.

Using the ADF UI, how can I instruct the copy activity to map `RawJson.text` to the column `Text`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a query to parse the JSON column and get the text value as a new column.

**SQL query:**

```
select type, RawJson,
 JSON_VALUE(RawJson,'$.text') AS Text
from test1
```

[image]

Mapping:

[image]

Comment: This is how I would do it, or create a view in the database that structured the columns using `JSON_VALUE` and just select straight from that.